# Use SwiftUI to turn the text overlapping the rectangle in ScrollView white

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, blend-mode

I created a view similar to a wheel picker, and when I swiped the scrollView, I wanted the color of the text to change to white when it coincided with the rectangle.I can use `.blendMode` to achieve the effects in the images, but when the background changes, the effect also changes. I want to know if there is any method that can be unaffected by the background color.I searched for a long time but couldn't find a suitable solution. If you could provide any help, I would greatly appreciate it.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIIntrospect
import Combine
@_spi(Advanced) import SwiftUIIntrospect

struct TimePickerView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = TimerPickerViewModel()
    private let date = ["", "1", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", "110", "120", ""]
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("bg")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(0..<date.count, id: \.self) { index in
                        let time = date[index]
                        Text(time + (time.isEmpty ? "":" MIN"))
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                    }
                }
                .font(.system(size: 25))
                .foregroundStyle(Color(hex: 0x638FFF))
                .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: TimerOffsetPreferenceKey.self,
                                    value: geometry.frame(in: .named("TimePickeView")).origin.y)
                })
                .onPreferenceChange(TimerOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                    viewModel.contentOffset = -value
                }
            }
            .introspect(.scrollView, on: .iOS(.v15, .v16, .v17), customize: { scrollView in
                viewModel.scrollView = scrollView
            })
            .frame(height: 150)
            .coordinateSpace(name: "TimePickeView")
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .fill(Color(hex: 0x638FFF))
                .frame(width: 180, height: 50)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

class TimerPickerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    private var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    init() {
        $contentOffset
            .dropFirst(2)
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.3), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .sink { [weak self] output in
                let remainder = Int(output) % 50
                var offset = Int(output) - remainder + (remainder > 25 ? 50:0)
                offset = max(0, min(offset, 1000))
                self?.scrollView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat(offset)), animated: true)
            }
            .store(in: &cancellable)
    }
}

struct TimerOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value += nextValue()
    }
}

#Preview {
    TimePickerView()
}
```

The following is a similar effect that I want:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get it to work using `.blendMode` with the following small changes:

- apply `.compositingGroup()` to the `ZStack`
- set the background using `.background`

```swift
ZStack {
    // content as before, but without the background image
}
.compositingGroup()
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background( /* the image */ )
```

The modifier `.compositingGroup` isolates the effect of the blend mode to the contents of the `ZStack`. However, whether or not it works may depend on the colors you are using and/or the color scheme in operation (light/dark mode).

As a more general-purpose solution, I would suggest showing a `Capsule` shape which has the list of dates shown as an overlay, clipped to the shape. This way, you can use any styling you like.

- To keep the position of the overlay synchronized with the scrolled list behind it, the scroll offset can be applied as a y-offset.
- The scroll offset can be detected using a `GeometryReader` in the background. You were doing this already, but you were then using a `PreferenceKey` to pass on the value. I would suggest, it is simpler to use an `.onChange` handler to update a state variable.
- The scroll position can be made sticky by using `.scrollTargetLayout`.
- The index of the scrolled item can be detected by using `.scrollPosition`. The selected index can then be derived from the scrolled index.

Here is an example of how it can be implemented this way. It does not need a `PreferenceKey`, nor does it use introspection.

```swift
struct TimePicker: View {
    private let rowHeight: CGFloat = 50
    private let date = ["", "1", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "55", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100", "110", "120", ""]
    @State private var scrollOffset = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var scrolledIndex: Int?

    var selectedIndex: Int {
        min((scrolledIndex ?? 0) + 1, date.count - 2)
    }

    private var dateList: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(Array(date.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, time in
                Text(time + (time.isEmpty ? "":" MIN"))
                    .frame(height: rowHeight)
            }
        }
        .font(.system(size: 25))
    }

    private var scrollDetector: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let minY = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView).minY
            Color.clear
                .onChange(of: minY) { oldVal, newVal in
                    scrollOffset = newVal
                }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                dateList
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue) // 0x638FFF
                    .background(scrollDetector)
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $scrolledIndex)
            .scrollTargetLayout()
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)

            Capsule()
                .fill(.blue) // 0x638FFF
                .frame(width: 180, height: rowHeight)
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    dateList
                        .foregroundStyle(.background)
                        .offset(y: scrollOffset - rowHeight)
                }
                .clipped()
                .allowsHitTesting(false)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 3 * rowHeight)
        .padding(.bottom, 50)
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Text("Selected index = \(selectedIndex)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! Just for completeness, I added a note about using `compositingGroup`, which might work for certain color schemes.